# How to add a relative link into a message in ModelAndView inside @Controller

Tags: java, spring

I have this code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/welcome**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView defaultPage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("message", "This is default page! To login, click here");
    model.setViewName("hello");
    return model;
}
```

I would like to add a relative link to the message in the model (at the 'here' word). Something like `/login`, so then it would be handled by the main controller.

I am sure there is a right way of doing that, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You should make it from view level, depending what template engine you use it should look like, e.g.:

```
<a href="<c:url value='/login'/>">here</a>
```

(jsp)

```
<a th:href="@{/login}">here</a>
```

(thymeleaf)

Comment: Alright, thanks, but why? Does that mean I can't generate a message I wish from the controller and point it to the link I want?

Comment: Because, you know, I want the message to disappear when user is actually logged in.

Comment: Still you should do such things in view. Just look for 'if logged in thymeleaf' or 'if logged in jsp' keywords and you will find the best way to render the message.

Comment: You shouldn't, model should be used to pass dynamic parameters to the view. Whole message should be placed in view in your case; it is also good practice to use messages functionality. Check out this link https://www.ricston.com/blog/dynamic-view-messages-spring-mvc/